# GNU Screen hangs in ConEmu

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, gnu-screen, conemu

I just did an update of Cygwin on a Windows 7 box.  When I open ConEmu to a Cygwin Bash terminal, everything seems fine.  However, if I run GNU Screen, the terminal locks up until I forcibly kill screen.exe using a Task Manager.  This was not happening before the update.

I tried other updates with other mirrors but it doesn't seem to help.  I tried removing my .screenrc file, it also didn't help.  I tried downgrading my version Screen to 4.3.1-1 and it didn't help either.  I tried the newest version of ComEmu and it didn't help.  I tried running Screen from MinTTY and it works okay (but MinTTY has some other problems with Screen so it's not a good solution for me).

I had another Window 7 machine and it also broke as soon as I updated Cygwin.  It must be some sort of new version of some sub-library that causes this issue.  Anyone have this same issue?  Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: First of all, try to run screen in the standart Windows console (neither ConEmu, not mintty). Does the problem repeat? Then report to cygwin maintainers. https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsys.html

Answer (score 0):

I did test it with cmd.exe and and everything is fine.  It's probably something wrong with ConEmu.  There really is nothing special about my setup, so anyone reading this is welcome to try it themselves.

I just ended up switching to [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console/wiki/Downloads). Also, [This blog](https://blog.openshift.com/upgrade-cygwin-to-console2-and-improve-the-productivity-of-openshifts-rhc-client-tools-on-wind/) showed how to get started.  It took five minutes to download and install.  Problem solved.

It's too bad ConEmu is a really wonderful product and full of features, but all I really need is Screen to work again.  Maybe I'll try again later.

Comment: Without further exact information nobody can help you. For example, process tree from [ProcessExplorer](https://conemu.github.io/en/ProcessExplorer.html), [memory dump](https://conemu.github.io/en/MemoryDump.html) of screen process, what do you mean by "locks up" exactly, what happens in [RealConsole](https://conemu.github.io/en/RealConsole.html) and so on. Anyway, this exceeds the superused QA purpose and you'll go to [project issues](https://conemu.github.io/en/Issues.html).